# Use Cauchy Inequalities to find an upper bound for $|f^4(i)|$ and $|f^4(0)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Let's suppose that $f$ is differentiable on a disk $B_{10}(r)$, and $|f(z)| \leq 54$ for $z$ on the circle $|z-i| = 3$. My goal is to use Cauchy Inequalities to find an upper bound for $|f^4(i)|$ and $|f^4(0)|$.

The first of these is simply a direct application of the Cauchy Inequality formula. However, the hint I was given for $|f^4(0)|$ is this statement:

> A strict maximum of the absolute value of an analytic function can't be attained at the interior point of a set.

Using this information, my guess was that because $0$ is in the interior of the circle $|z-i| = 3$, we cannot find an upper bound for it. Hence, finding an upper bound for $|f^4(0)|$ is not possible.

This sounds fine at first, but I run into a question: isn't $i$ also an interior point of $|z-i| = 3$? If that's true, why does a contradiction not arise with this point as was the case for $z_0 = 0$?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why a contradiction doesn't arise with the point $z_{0}=i$, but I know that the Cauchy's Inequalities theorem does say that if $f(z)$ is a differentiable function on a domain $G$ containing the circle $\gamma_{\rho} : |z −z_{0}| = \rho$ and its interior, then $|f^{n}(z_{0})| ≤ n! \frac{M_{\rho}}{\rho^{n}}$, where $\displaystyle M_{\rho} = \displaystyle \max_{\displaystyle z \in \gamma_{\displaystyle \rho}}|f(z)|$. So, in the case of $z_{0}=i$, we have, by Cauchy's Inequalities, that $|f^{(4)}(i)|\leq 4! \frac{54}{3^4} = 16$.

Comment: The hint isn't trying to say that the possible values are unbounded; in fact, it's trying to say that the possible values are constrained by the maximum value on the boundary of the set.

Comment: @GregMartin, regarding the case for $z_{0} = 0$, would that case just be bounded by the case for $z_{0}=i$, then?

Comment: Typically for problems like this, about analytic functions defined on a disk, one can get extra mileage by composing $f$ with a linear fractional transformation that preserves the circle $|z-i|=3$ and maps $i$ to $0$.

Comment: @GregMartin, if you'd like to answer this question, there is now a 50 point bounty on it,

Comment: @Dr.MV there is a 50 point bounty on this question now

Comment: @K.M.: Are you looking for $\left|f^{(4)}(z)\right|=\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}^4}{\mathrm{d}z^4}f(z)\right|$ or $\left|f^4(z)\right|=\left|f(z)\right|^4$?

Comment: @K.M.: that statement is not true unless one restricts to *non-constant* analytic functions. Consider for instance the analytic function $f(z)=1$. It attains its absolute maximum at every point.

Comment: @robjohn, the fourth derivative; not the fourth power.

Comment: @JessyCat: then I don't understand how the hint helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Looking for $\boldsymbol{f^{(4)}(z)}$**

If $\left|w-i\right|=3$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\left|f^{(4)}(i)\right|
&=\frac{4!}{2\pi}\left|\oint\frac{f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w}{(w-i)^5}\right|\\
&\le\frac{4!}{2\pi}\oint\frac{\left|f(w)\right|\,\left|\mathrm{d}w\right|}{\left|w-i\right|^5}\\
&\le\frac{24}{2\pi}\frac{54\cdot6\pi}{3^5}\\[6pt]
&=16
\end{align}
$$
If $\left|w-i\right|=3$, then $\left|w-0\right|\ge2$
$$
\begin{align}
\left|f^{(4)}(0)\right|
&=\frac{4!}{2\pi}\left|\oint\frac{f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w}{(w-0)^5}\right|\\
&\le\frac{4!}{2\pi}\oint\frac{\left|f(w)\right|\,\left|\mathrm{d}w\right|}{\left|w-0\right|^5}\\
&\le\frac{24}{2\pi}\frac{54\cdot6\pi}{2^5}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{243}2
\end{align}
$$

---

**Looking for $\boldsymbol{f^4(z)}$**

If $\left|w-i\right|=3$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\left|f(i)\right|
&=\frac1{2\pi}\left|\oint\frac{f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w}{w-i}\right|\\
&\le\frac1{2\pi}\oint\frac{\left|f(w)\right|\,\left|\mathrm{d}w\right|}{\left|w-i\right|}\\
&\le\frac1{2\pi}\frac{54\cdot6\pi}{3}\\[6pt]
&=54
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left|f^4(i)\right|\le54^4
$$
If $\left|w-i\right|=3$, then $\left|w-0\right|\ge2$
$$
\begin{align}
\left|f(0)\right|
&=\frac1{2\pi}\left|\oint\frac{f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w}{w-0}\right|\\
&\le\frac1{2\pi}\oint\frac{\left|f(w)\right|\,\left|\mathrm{d}w\right|}{\left|w-0\right|}\\
&\le\frac1{2\pi}\frac{54\cdot6\pi}{2}\\[6pt]
&=81
\end{align}
$$
But the maximum of $\left|f(z)\right|$ on $\left|z-i\right|\le3$ is attained on the boundary $\left|z-i\right|=3$, where $\left|f(z)\right|\le54$. Therefore,
$$
\left|f^4(0)\right|\le54^4
$$